# Rank ordering a rows of a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, ranking

I was was if there is a way to rank-order rows of my `Data` below such that rows that **simultaneously** have the largest values on each of `risk1`, `risk2` and `risk3` (*NOT TOTAL Of the three*) are at the top?

For example, in my `Desired_output`, you see that `id == 4` **simultaneously** has the largest values on `risk1`, `risk2` and `risk3` (`4,3,2`).

For all other `id`s, there is a `1` or `0` on at least one of the `risk1`, `risk2` and `risk3`.

Note: Tie's are fine. `4,3,2 == 2,3,4 == 3,2,4`.

```
Data = data.frame(id=1:4,risk1 = c(1,3,5,4), risk2 = c(8,2,1,3), risk3 = c(0,1,4,2))

Desired_output = read.table(h=T,text="
id  risk1 risk2 risk3
4     4     3     2
3     5     1     4
2     3     2     1
1     1     8     0
")
```

Comment: Do you want `Data[rank(do.call(pmax, Data[-1])),]`

Comment: Your ranking scheme is somewhat ambiguous. For example, how would a row with `c(2, 3, 4)` rank in comparison to the example data?

Comment: @jblood94, same rank as `(4,3,2)`

Comment: *"you see that id == 4 simultaneously has the largest values on risk1, risk2 and risk3 (4,3,2)"*. I don't see that at all. The highest `risk1` values is 5, not 4. The highest `risk2`  value is 8, not 3. The highest `risk3` value is 4, not 2. What do you see that makes that the "highest"?

Comment: How is 1 8 0 or 8 1 0 ranked better than 4 3 2

Comment: @akrun, 1 8 0 or 8 1 0 ranked lower than 4 3 2.

Comment: @Reza can you please tell us the logic for that.  8 is larger than any of 4 3 2

Comment: @akrun, there is a 0 in the combination while 4 3 2 has no 0 at all.

Comment: what if it was 1 .e. `1 8 1` and `4 3 2`

Comment: 1 8 1 or 8 1 1 are ranked lower than 4 3 2.

Comment: So would the rows with id 2 and id 4 rank the same? Is the ranking system something like recursively removing rows with the smallest number in one of the columns?

Comment: You need to explain the logic more clearly. You say what you **don't** want to rank by: the total, but you don't say what you **do** want to rank by. You don't like 0s or 1s, but you don't give any indication of how to penalize those. I'd guess maybe you want to rank by the sum of squares, but 8 is so big it would dominate, so I don't think that's what you want...

Comment: @jblood94, no, `3     2     1` is ranked lower than `4     3     2` because the latter doesn't have 1 anywhere. The smallest in the latter in 2.

Comment: Maybe you want to rank by the row sum, but treat the 1s as 0s and the 0s as -5s? That would work for your example data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this helps - loop over the rows, `sort` the elements, `paste`, convert to numeric, use that to `order` the rows

```
Data[order(-apply(Data[-1], 1, \(x) 
     as.numeric(paste(sort(x), collapse = "")))),]
```

-output

```
   id risk1 risk2 risk3
4  4     4     3     2
3  3     5     1     4
2  2     3     2     1
1  1     1     8     0
```

Comment: A little follow-up, can we attach the ranks as a new column? I want to see which rows receive the same rank in my actual data.-- Thank you

Comment: @Reza Yes, you can use `Data$ord <- order(-apply(Data[-1], 1, \(x) 
     as.numeric(paste(sort(x), collapse = "")))); Data[Data$ord,]`

Comment: @Reza Or could be `v1 <- apply(Data[-1], 1, \(x)       as.numeric(paste(sort(x), collapse = "")));Data$Rank <- rank(-v1);Data[order(-v1),]`

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick:

```
library(dplyr)

Data %>% 
  arrange(-row_number())
```

```
  id risk1 risk2 risk3
1  4     4     3     2
2  3     5     1     4
3  2     3     2     1
4  1     1     8     0
```

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to understand how this answer considers the values in the 'risk' columns. It's just a coincidence that simply reversing the order of the data gives the same output as OP's desired. Cheers

Comment: @Henrik you are right. I saw this pattern and provided the solution. Because of the simplicity I was happy that I recognized the pattern. That is all. At least it gives the desired output. I can easily remove the answer, no problem. And the coincidence just by chance seems strange for me.